# I want to post dropdown text instead value in MVC DropdownFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, drop-down-menu

I want to know if there is any possibility of me posting Text value from a nested Dropdown in MVC??

I have been able to populate the dropdown with my database values and it is cascaded that when  the first dropdown it picked, It automatically populate the second dropdown with a json result. I want to post the text value from the dropdown, it is posible??

This is my controller with the JSON call

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SchoolRegViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase Logo)
{
    var queryCountry = _countryState.GetAllCountry().Select(s => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = s.CountryId.ToString(),
        Text = s.CountryName,
        Selected = false
    });
    model.Country = queryCountry.AsEnumerable();

    var country = model.Country.Select(x => x.Text).Single();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            ....
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}

public JsonResult StateList(int? id)
{
    if (id != null)
    {
        var state = _countryState.GetAllState(id.Value);
        return Json(new SelectList(state, "CountryId", "StateName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new { }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

this is my jquery that populate the second dropdown with json result

```
jQuery(function ($) {

$(function ()
{
    $('#CountryId').change(function () {
        $.getJSON('/Registration/Registration/StateList/' + $('#CountryId').val(), function (data) {
            var items = '<option>-- Select State --</option>';
            $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                items += "<option value = '" + state.Value + "'>" + state.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $('#State').html(items);
            $('#State option:selected').text();
        });
    });
});
```

});

View

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="text" class="control-label">Country</label>
    <div class="controls">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, Model.Country, "-- Choose Country --", new { id = "CountryId", required="true"})
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label for="text" class="control-label">State/Provinces</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select name="State" id="State" data-rule-required="true">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the `value` parameter the same as what you're putting in for the text.

```
new SelectList(state, "StateName", "StateName")
```

And:

```
items += "<option value = '" + state.Text + "'>" + state.Text + "</option>";
```

Comment: But is it still going to send the CountryId for state list Json to return??

Because I did that but it did not return the State list cuz the json isnt getting the ID instead Name so how do i go around it to send ID for json and Post Text for database??

Comment: You can't. The posted value is the posted value. You can post the id and then use the id to look up the thing from the database to get the text, in situations where you need that, but otherwise, if you want the text, you must post the text.

Comment: Yea I thought it was possible that way

Thanks for your help